# A singular word for statements like "all Brits have bad teeth" or "all Italians are romantic" or "all Americans are uneducated/overweight"

Tags: single-word-requests

Not prejudice but making assumptions about a culture or group of people either negative or positive.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a [**stereotype**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stereotype):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : something conforming to a fixed or general pattern
> *especially* : a standardized mental picture that is held in common by members of a group and that represents an oversimplified opinion, prejudiced attitude, or uncritical judgment
>
> ---
>
> The words *cliché* and *stereotype* have a good deal in common. Both come from French, both were originally printers’ terms, and both have come to take on somewhat negative meanings in modern use.
>
> Their original meanings are essentially synonymous, referring to printing blocks from which numerous prints could be made. In fact, *cliché* means *stereotype* in French. Their modern meanings, however, are quite distinct. *Cliché* is today overwhelmingly encountered in reference to something hackneyed, such as an overly familiar or commonplace phrase, theme, or expression. *Stereotype* is most frequently now employed to refer to an often unfair and untrue belief that many people have about all people or things with a particular characteristic.
>
> // movies have *stereotyped* the hooker with a heart of gold ad nauseam

Although this definition includes the phrase *prejudiced attitude*, and a stereotype *can* be prejudiced, many stereotypes are not actually prejudiced but simple uncritical generalizations.